# Convert SQl to LINQ (with case statement Method)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How to convert LINQ from SQL query with Case statement Method.

```
case when c.[Candidate_CreateBy] like 'A%'
        then
        ( select[Admin_Name] from [dbo].[Admin] a where  c.Candidate_CreateBy = a.Admin_Id)
        else 

         c.[Candidate_Name]
 end As "name"
 FROM [dbo].[Candidate] c
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard operator ?: is doing job.

```
var query = 
   from c in ctx.Candidate
   select EF.Functions.Like("A%") ? 
      ctx.Admin.Where(a => c.Candidate_CreateBy == a.Admin_Id).Select(a => a.Admin_Name)
      : c.Candidate_Name;
```